# Git filter with cygwin sed on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I am trying to implement a basic string replacement in the header of my code with `git filter clean` feature.

Here is what I did so far:

I created a `.gitattributes`:

```
; Filters for .c, .h files
*.c filter=code_filters
*.h filter=code_filters
```

Then in my project `config`:

```
[filter "code_filters"]
    clean = sed.exe -e "s/Project\s*:.*/Project : My Current Project/"
```

Since I am on Windows, I use sed from cygwin which is in my path.
The regular expression seems correct:

```
$ echo "Project :" | sed.exe -e "s/Project\s*:.*/Project : My Current Project/"
Project : My Current Project
```

Unfortunately, the filter syntax is not accepted. For any git command I get:

```
fatal: bad config file line 14 in .git/config
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Note: I left the .exe extension to focus on the Windows aspect of my question. I'll remove it when it will work!

Comment: when you run your example from cygwin, do you run in bash mode - I think git runs in bash, potentially replace your double quote with simple quote

Comment: Yes I tried that too but it doesn't work better with ' '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by escaping the / character so code looks like

```
[filter "code_filters"]
    clean = sed -e 's/Project\\s*:.*/Project : My Current Project/'
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. That was what I wanted to test. But at the moment my repo is dead. I am going to open another question to fix it. Then I'll test your solution!